# OpenGL indices Array

Tags: c++, opengl, grid, terrain

I have a class `terrain` which create a grid of `Quad`s. I do it like this

```
for(int z=0; z<_length;z++){
            for(int x=0; x<_width;x++){
                vertices.push_back(vec3((float)x*250, 0.f, (float)z*250));
    }
}
for(int z=0; z<(_length-1);++z){
    for(int x=0; x<(_width-1);++x){
        int index = z*_width+x; 
        Vertex _vertices[] = {
            Vertex(vertices.at(index),vec3(0, 0, 0)),
            Vertex(vertices.at(index+1),vec3(0, 0, 0)),
            Vertex(vertices.at(index+_width),vec3(0, 0, 0)),
            Vertex(vertices.at(index+1+_width),vec3(0,0,0))
        };

        unsigned short indices[]= {index,index + 1,index + 
            _width,index + 1,index +  _width,index +  _width + 1};
        Quad quad(_vertices, 4, indices, 6);
        squares.push_back(quad);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The vertices and the logic are correct, but the indices aren't, for some reason. here is the output for this code : 
[image]
But when I change this indices to this :

```
            unsigned short indices[]= {0,1,2,1,2,3};
```

It works great : 
[image]

The problem is I don't understand why this line

```
        unsigned short indices[]= {index,index + 1,index + 
            _width,index + 1,index +  _width,index +  _width + 1};
```

doesn't work. And if it worked, my grid would consume a lot less ressources. If someone could explain me why it doesn't work, It would be great, thanks you.
In case you need to know how I draw a Quad, here is the code :

```
class Quad{
public:
    Quad(Vertex *_vertices, int _n, unsigned short * _indices, unsigned short _numIndices){
        for(int i=0; i < _numIndices; i++){
            indices.push_back(_indices[i]);
        } 

        for(int i=0; i<_n; i++){
            vec3 v = vec3(_vertices[i].position, _lengthPower);
            position.push_back(v);                     
        }
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVertexArray);
        glBindVertexArray(mVertexArray);

        glGenBuffers(1, &mPositionBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mPositionBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec3)*position.size(), position.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

        glGenBuffers(1, &mIndicesBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned short)*indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    }

    void draw(){
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mPositionBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBuffer);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    }
    ~Quad(){

    }
private:

    std::vector<unsigned short> indices; 
    std::vector<vec3> position; 
    GLuint mVertexArray; 
    GLuint mPositionBuffer; 
    GLuint mIndicesBuffer; 
};
```

I'm using, OpenGL, glm, glfw etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code uses parts of two solutions to draw the terrain. Each one would work just fine by itself, but this is halfway between.

### Separate Quads

Most of the code shown treats the terrain as a set of separate quads. In this case, you have `length - 1` times `width - 1` quad instances, each one with 4 vertices and 6 indices.

This is exactly what your `Quad` class implements. It stores 4 vertices and 6 indices in its own pair of VBOs, and sets up a VAO with the attribute state. Then you instantiate a `Quad` for each square in your terrain.

Since the vertices for each `Quad` are stored in its own buffers, the implication is that the indices reference vertices within this buffer. Which means that the indices are in the range 0 to 3, which is exactly what you found to be working.

The downside of this choice is that it will be inefficient for large terrains. You'll have a lot of objects (2 VBOs and 1 VBO for each quad), and need a separate draw call for rendering each quad. You're also not sharing vertices, having 4 copies of most vertices in your overall data structure.

You could actually drop the indices for this approach, and use a `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4)` call to draw the quad. But the other disadvantages remain.

### Shared Vertices

A much more efficient approach is to store the entire terrain in a single VBO. Your code started doing that here:

```
for(int z=0; z<_length;z++){
    for(int x=0; x<_width;x++){
        vertices.push_back(vec3((float)x*250, 0.f, (float)z*250));
    }
}
```

But then you do not follow through with it. What you need to do is store these `vertices` in a single VBO for the entire terrain.

Since the indices will then reference vertices by their position in this vertex buffer that contains **all** vertices in the terrain, the index calculations start to make much more sense:

```
int index = z*_width+x; 
unsigned short indices[]= {index,index + 1,index + 
    _width,index + 1,index +  _width,index +  _width + 1};
```

This would be the indices for a quad within this overall VBO. You would want to change this to also build an index array for the entire terrain. This could look something like this:

```
for(int z = 0; z < _length - 1; ++z) {
    for(int x = 0; x < _width; ++x) {
        indices.push_back(z * width + x);
        indices.push_back((z + 1) * width + x);
    }
}
```

This can then be rendered using `length - 1` triangle strips. with `2 * _width` indices each. The common vertices are shared, which makes the whole thing much more efficient. You could reduce the rendering to a single draw call by using slightly more advanced features, like primitive restart.

The only downside is that it might seem less object oriented to not have objects for each quad. But that seems sort of artificial anyway. You have a terrain that consists of a grid of vertices. I see nothing wrong with having a terrain object containing this whole grid. And I like classes and objects as much as the next guy (some say too much...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I wish I could upvote your answer more. I was thinking to store all the vertices and indices in one single VBO, but with your explanation I'm sure that's what I should do. Thank you again, it was really helpful !